# Software or extension to make possible using credentials but not leaving password to third parties

Tags: password-manager

I'm working with some collaborators as part of my every day workflow.
Sometimes I have to give them access to my shared hosting accounts, even to my WHCMS accounts in order to solve problems regarding hosting. On top of that, some other times I have to give them access to some websites - Wordpress based mostly, but that's an issue only if they have admin priviledges.
Is there any software or browser extension that allows them to use credentials for login, but never see passwords?

An option will be AccessURL, e new startup app that generates URLs for each of the accounts. The problem is when I'm done with some project and certain collaborators should not be allowed to access the accounts anymore, because I have to reset the passwords all over again. So, in AccessURL's case, I need to generate other URLs for other people involved, giving up the old URLs.

When I work with a couple of credentials that's fine. But once the portofolio scales, I need to change several (tens even hundreds) of password at once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### Dashlane

You can try [Dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com/), a password manager app and secure digital wallet. It comes with an apps for most of the operating systems, mobiles and as a plugin for web-browsers, which makes it easy to use. The app's premium feature enables users to securely sync the data between an unlimited number of devices on all platforms.

You can share your specific passwords, payment details or security notes to other collaborators with different level of access (e.g. without revealing password it-self).

See also: [Security analysis of Dashlane](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74656/11825).

Answer (score 1):

**LastPass Enterprise**

Look at [LastPass Enterprise](https://www.lastpass.com/enterprise/) which has many of the features you are looking for. You can share passwords with other users without revealing passwords. You also have fine grained access over who has access to it.

LastPass has extensions for all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE) and mobile (iOS and Android).

Disclaimer: I use the Personal version and it works well for me. I know folks who use the Enterprise version and they have good things to say about it.